# How can I put button on cell of ag grid table's every row for my template?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, button, ag-grid

Is it possible to put buttons (as we did at basic table table-hover) for ag-grid table? I was looking for solution but i couldn't find. Ag-grid table is so complicated.

Comment: Did you have a look at [cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell Renderer

```
{header:"column",
 cellRenderer:function(params){
 return '<button type="button"> Delete </button>'
 }
}
```